# List doesn't filter properly using Contains in combobox

Tags: c#

I am trying to come up with a solution where I can search items inside a combo box that contain certain word/phrase. I tried using the AutoComplete text box functionality, but that only searches for the first word which is no good to me.

I have followed the example provided at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c229a73-cdad-4fa3-95db-97f9ff7810c1/autocomplete-match-on-contains-not-startswith?forum=netfxbcl

I have initiated 2 lists

```
public List<string> listOnit = new List<string>();
public List<string> listNew = new List<string>();
```

I then load the data into a comboBox

```
if (rdr.HasRows == true)
        {
           // var source = new List<string>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

               // myCollectionSales.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
                listOnit.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
            }
            rdr.Close();
            //textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCollectionSales;
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listOnit.ToArray());
        }
```

and have a TextUpdate event handler to filter the list when text has changed

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        listNew.Clear();

        foreach (var item in listOnit)
        {
            if (item.Contains(this.comboBox1.Text))
            {
                listNew.Add(item);
            }
        }
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listNew.ToArray());
        comboBox1.SelectionStart = this.comboBox1.Text.Length;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

I am coming across a problem where the search results don't return what I expect. For example, I search for the string "Bud" and I only get the following results

http://prntscr.com/ppkatd

While in the database, there is also Budweiser 33cl and Keg Budweiser (http://prntscr.com/ppkbu4), for example, which is fetched on the first list.

Should I be using a different method, rather than "Contains"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are using different cases?

Try with .ToLower():

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    listNew.Clear();

    foreach (var item in listOnit)
    {
        if (item.ToLower().Contains(this.comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            listNew.Add(item);
        }
    }
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listNew.ToArray());
    comboBox1.SelectionStart = this.comboBox1.Text.Length;
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! I didn't think about case difference, that's my bad. Thankfully it was something simple.

Comment: I just came across another issue and was wondering if you'd be able to help me. When I start searching in the combo box, I need to press the letter twice. What happens is when I press "K" it opens the combo box right away and shows me the first item with letter "K". I then have to press "K" again to erase what's there and be able to type the rest of the word. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps there is another built-in handler? What controls are you using?

Comment: I'm not using another combobox in this windows form, it's the only one. I am checking if "Enter" was pressed, but not sure if that would cause an issue?

Comment: Try to turn of autocomplete.

Comment: AutoCompleteMode is set to None. Is there another way in which I should turn it off?